# Pegar um registro assim que o mesmo é salvo no banco

Tags: php, mysql

Estou gravando um registr em meu banco de dados assim:

```
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

include 'conexao.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "insert into sessoes
                              (tipo, data) values
                              ('".$tipo."', '".$data."')");
//o registro grava corretamente

if (!$result) { //vejo se tem algum erro
    throw new Exception(mysqli_error($con)."insert into sessoes
                                            (tipo, data) values
                                            ('".$tipo."', '".$data."')");
}else{
  mysqli_commit($con); //dou um commit no banco de dados
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * sessoes order by id desc");
  //NA LINHA ACIMA, TENTO PEGAR O ÚLTIMO REGISTRO SALVO, MAS O MESMO NÃO É RETORNADO, MESMO QUE EU VEJO NO BANCO E ELE ESTÁ LÁ
  $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //linh fica null
  $idSessao = $linha['id']; //idSessao fica null
  //header('location:participaram.php?idSessao='.$idSessao);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Como podem ver no código, ele grava os dados no banco, mas não me retorna o registro salvo. O que pode estar acontecendo de errado?

A tabela `sessoes`:

```
id int
data date
tipo int
```

Comment: Tem a modelagem da tabela ``sessoes `` para passar?

Comment: @MarlonTiedt alterei a pergunta, embora que o erro nao é na tabela, ela está salvando normal. só não me retorna na hora que preciso (assim que salvo), se eu trocar de página, ela aparece

Comment: [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) retorna um array de array associativo. O correto para acessar o ID dos registros retornados é : `$linha[0]["id"]`

Comment: @PanterA `$linha` está null

Comment: @ValdeirPsr não conheço essa função. pra que serve e em que local do código devo usar?

Comment: A função `mysqli_insert_id($con);` serve para retornar o último ID inserido no banco de dados.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr funcionou perfeitamente. se quiser pode incluir a resposta pra ganhar seus pontos. grato aos outros também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### O erro

O erro está na *query*. Faltou o `FROM`. O correto é: `select * FROM sessoes order by id desc`

> Abaixo explico o porque não deve utilizar dessa forma para capturar o último ID.

#### Soluções

Utilize `mysqli_insert_id` para retornar o último ID inserido.

```
  $idSessao = mysqli_insert_id($con);
  header('location:participaram.php?idSessao='.$idSessao);
```

Além disso, você também pode utilizar a *query*:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS lastId;
```

É a mesma coisa, porém um pouco mais de código (devido ao PHP).

#### Obervações

Há um problema em utilizar `select * sessoes order by id desc`. Quando tratamos de performance, esse código não é recomendado. Talvez no inicio e em *localhost*, pareça interessante, o problema é que em um servidor de produção com milhares de acesso isso se torna um pesadelo, principalmente quando se tem muitos dados inseridos.

Antes de utilizar um código *MySQL* utilize o `EXPLAIN` na frente, dessa forma você conseguirá ver como sua *query* se comporta quando executada.

Ex: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM sessoes ORDER BY id desc`